# How do I configure IIS 7 to allow a hosted site to communicate with a windows service using a third party cookies that stores session id?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, cookies, windows-services

I have a website that is being hosted on IIS 7 that communicates with a Ingenico signature device via a windows service. When I was originally testing the site functionality on my local pc, the site would open and I would click the button that triggers a GetSignature() method. This method uses HTTPWebRequests and HTTPWebResponses to open a connection to the signature device, claim the device, prompt signature, retrieve signature, release the device, and close the connection.

Here is a small snippet of code used:

[GetSignatureCodeSnippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvv7l.png)

The following HTTP requests use the session-id from this cookie for a single transaction. When running this locally, I had to set my browser to allow third party cookies otherwise, a session-id was never stored and you get Http404 errors.

Where I am having trouble is I have added all the functionality to my site and updated my test site to include this new functionality. The test site is hosted on IIS 7. When trying to communicate with the signature device, I am now getting Http404 because it is not allowing the third party cookie. How/Can I configure IIS to accept the third party cookie from the windows service?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Your questions will get a much better response if you put the code in the question.  Using links to other sites is not a great idea for a number of reasons.  People also want to have actual source code rather than an image since images are really hard to edit.  Please see [How to Ask a Good Question](/help/how-to-ask) and provide an [mcve]

Comment: Can you clarify the archtecture? Is it Your App -> 3rd Party -> Signature Pad, or something else?

If you truly need to be able to read a 3rd party cookie, that's entirely out of the server's control and is set in the browser or device with an "Allow 3rd party cookies" option.

Comment: The Ingenico company has a windows service that is installed on a server (server1) that is used to communicate with the signature device, which is accessible via IP address. In the HTTPWebRequests, you pass data in the URI to the windows service so it knows which device to communicate with.The web app, which is hosted on the same server (server1) is configured to send these HTTPWebRequests, but for a single transaction containing multiple web requests, it needs to have a session id that it gets from a 3rd party cookie.

Comment: When I have a copy of the web app hosted locally on my laptop, not on IIS on server, it  accepts the cookie and the app is able to communicate properly with signature device through the service hosted on server1. It is only once the web app is hosted on IIS that this service fails with a HTTP(404) with an InnerException of Session-ID invalid. Currently the web app communicates the first HTTPWebRequest properly and receives a response, but when trying to do the next request in the same transaction, the session-id is invalid due to not receiving it from the cookie. Hope this helps better explain